# ajax live search with node.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, request, response

I'm new to node.js. Now I'm trying to write a simple website where users can input something for the server to process, and receive a result, e.g. search for something.

I try to implement it as follows:

1. write the `index.html`
2. write the `server.js`, it creates a server, and display the index page using `var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html'); response.end(index);`
3. add ajax codes in index.html, to receive input from users and send it to the server
4. the last step will be adding codes in server.js, which processes the request and send a result to ajax to display it.

My question is about step 4. In the server.js, when it receives ajax request, should it somehow add the result to the index.html file, and send back using`response.end(index)`, OR send back only the result? If the latter one, which I tried, it will send both the index.html page and the result. But I only want the result.

Below is the two files `index.html` and `server.js`:

index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Client search using Ajax -->

<head>
    <title>live search</title>
    <script>
        function getResults(query) {
        if (query.length===0) { 
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1:2000/search?"+query,true);
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <hr>
    <input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="getResults(this.value)"/>
    <br>
    <div id="results">
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

---

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'ContentType': 'text/html'});
res.end(index);

//codes for request processing
result="";
var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
console.log(path);
if (path.length!==0) {
    result = "I'm the result";
}
res.write(result);

}).listen(2000);
```

Comment: If you want to send the data which you get in index.js(client) then you can send it to server using 
         socket.emit("EventName",{"data1": value1 , "data2" : value2})

Then you can receive it on server using event listeners like.

socket.on("EventName",function(data){
   //here you can use "data" parameter that contains values sent from client
});

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to use socket if I use index.html instead of .js? Actually what I wonder is, whether I should put the request processing codes inside the "createServer" block, or outside?

Comment: yeah exactly, on client side , you will include the client side socket library using "src" tag.

Comment: I have added the complete answer. please check.
Mark it as answered if it is answered.

Comment: So when the server receives the data, and processes it, and produces a result. How should I send the result back to the client. Now in my code, I tried to write the result after the index, and send back together. So is it possible to just send back the result?

Comment: okay, for this I editted the answer , check again.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly.
You want to send data between index.html and server.js on runtime.

For that, you need to use socket.io library.

For client(index.html)
use client side library for socket.io like following.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

Now If you want to send the data which you get in index.html(client) then you can send it to server using

```
socket.emit("EventName",{"data1": value1 , "data2" : value2 , [...]})
```

Then you can receive it on server using event listeners like.

```
socket.on("EventName",function(data){ 
//here you can use "data" parameter that contains values sent from client 
});
```

This was the client to server send/receive scenario.
For server to client, do the same thing i.e use socket.emit() on server to send to client and socket.on() at client to receive from server.

Comment: Thank you. It looks very elegant. I'll definitely try this way. But my real problem is, after the server received the data, and produce a result, how can I send the result back to the client? Now the issue is when I send the result back, the res.end(index) also sends the entire html page together with the result.

Comment: You should read the answer again. I said that if you want to send data from server to client, use "emit" and send the data, parallely on the client ,use socket.on() and receive the data and update your page using js or jquery or whatever